# Why isn't it enough put all JavaFX deps in the classpath w/o bothering about Java modules?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, java-platform-module-system

I've been trying to write Hello JavaFX app and faced with necessity consider about Java modules for starting the app.

F.e. **javafx-maven-plugin**'s **run** goal produce such startup command:

```
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [C:\java\zulu14.29.23-ca-jdk14.0.2-win_x64\bin\java.exe, 
--module-path, C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\14\javafx-base-14-win.jar;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\14\javafx-base-14.jar;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\14\javafx-controls-14-win.jar;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\14\javafx-controls-14.jar;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\14\javafx-graphics-14-win.jar;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\14\javafx-graphics-14.jar, 
--add-modules, javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics, 
-classpath, D:\project\target\classes, org.pkg.pkg.App]
```

But my project's structure doesn't mention Java module functionality - I didn't have **module-info.java** file.
Why can't I put all above JARs in the app classpath and be happy?
F.e.:

```
C:\java\zulu14.29.23-ca-jdk14.0.2-win_x64\bin\java.exe 
"-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=59556:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\bin" 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-classpath D:\project\target\classes;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\14\javafx-controls-14.jar;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\14\javafx-controls-14-win.jar;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\14\javafx-graphics-14.jar;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\14\javafx-graphics-14-win.jar;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\14\javafx-base-14.jar;
C:\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\14\javafx-base-14-win.jar 
org.pkg.pkg.App
```

If I'm right and understand [Packages and Modules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.5) spec correctly

- module JARs defined in the classpath treated as unnamed modules
- unnamed modules export all their packages, i.e. everything is visible in them

But I get an error

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

Could someoune please explain me where I'm wrong here, about how Java modules work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

***Warning:** Although the below shows what you want is possible, placing the JavaFX modules on the class-path is [not supported](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8256362). This means you should place JavaFX on the module-path, even when your own code is non-modular.*

---

You *can* put JavaFX on the class-path and completely ignore modules<sup>1</sup>. However, the one caveat is that your main class can no longer be assignable to `javafx.application.Application`<sup>2</sup>. The workaround is to create a separate main class that simply launches the JavaFX application. For example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Launcher {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // where YourApp.class is replaced with your Application class
    Application.launch(YourApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

---

<sup>1. Your can't *really* ignore modules completely. All code on the class-path ends up in the *unnamed module* and all the modules in the run-time image (i.e. the JDK/JRE) still function as named modules.</sup>

<sup>2. This is due to an implementation detail. Java contains code which allows you to launch JavaFX applications without a main method, so long as the main class is assignable to `Application`. But when it detects that the main class is assignable to `Application` it checks for `javafx.graphics` in the boot `ModuleLayer`—meaning it must be on the module-path—and if not there then it assumes JavaFX is missing.</sup>