# IllegalStateException due to thread issue

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm trying to create a window for an application. The size of the window is determined by getting the bounds of the primary screen. In order to do this I have created two classes.

RealMain class is the actual class that does everything:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RealMain extends Application {

    public static final double minWindowWidth;
    public static final double minWindowHeight;

    //Get primary screen bounds
    static {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        minWindowWidth = screenBounds.getWidth() / 2;
        minWindowHeight = screenBounds.getHeight() / 1.5;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(), minWindowWidth, minWindowHeight);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Main class is just an entry point into the program. All it does is call the main method of RealMain. Why do I need to use the Main class in the first place (why not just run the main method of RealMain)? It's because of a different problem I had, where I would get "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application." when running the program as a jar on macOS. Apparently setting a regular java class as an entry point will fix this (one place where I found this solution is [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/236)), hence I needed to create the Main class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RealMain.main(args);
    }
}
```

It works fine when I run the main method of the RealMain class. However, if I use the main method of the Main class, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at RealMain.<clinit>(RealMain.java:19)
    at Main.main(Main.java:4)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:441)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.setEventHandler(Screen.java:369)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.setScreenConfigurationListener(QuantumToolkit.java:684)
    at javafx.stage.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:74)
    ... 2 more
```

So it seems when running the program from Main class, the main thread is used to execute the static block, which seems to be what causes the error (as to why, I have no idea). Meanwhile when running the program from RealMain class, the JavaFX Application Thread is used for the static block, which works fine. I guess the logical solution would be to somehow force the program to change threads and execute the static block on the JavaFX Application Thread, but I have no idea how to do that.

Could anyone please help me figure this out?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632356/starting-javafx-from-main-method-of-class-which-doesnt-extend-application

Comment: Thank you! Calling the launch method did indeed fix the issue! I actually tried this before, but was not aware that you had to pass the extending class as an argument. Now I just need to see if the other issue I mentioned is fixed....

Comment: Is the "other issue" still the wrong-thread problem?

Comment: Yes, the JavaFX application components must run in the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

Comment: No the other issue was the "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application." i was getting when running the program as a .jar. While using the Main.class as the entry point did fix this, it was replaced by another error (such is the life I guess).

Comment: Unfortunately, [your main class cannot be assignable to `Application` if you put `javafx.graphics` on the class-path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63426436/6395627). Do you have to determine the screen size during class initialization? You can hide the fields behind methods so they don't have to be final. Or you could use a different deployment strategy; one that makes use of modules (e.g. `jlink` and/or `jpackage`).

Comment: This static block is simply illegal. You are trying to call JavaFX methods long before the JavaFX runtime is initialized. What else but problems do you expect from that? Just move that code into you start method.

Comment: As to why it is illegal: `static` blocks are executed when the class loader is invoked to load the class,  Whichever thread first forces the JVM to load the class is the one used to execute the Static block.  Almost all JavaFX code needs to run on the JavaFX app thread after the JavaFX system has been initialized.  The standard class loading system doesn't know anything about that.  You must adhere to the [application lifecycle](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) or stuff will likely fail.

Comment: Do you know when the JavaFX thread is created? I would've thought it happens the start/launch method is called, but it doesn't appear to be the case.